# Manhwa where the female protagonist is betrayed by her partner and best friend and gets reborn hundreds of years later

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I only read about the first two chapters like a year ago so I don't remember well, but if I remember correctly the protagonist had long blue hair at the beginning and everything was fully colored. She was some sort of Saint, had magical power and was gonna be the ruler of a kingdom I think.

She, her partner and her male friend (I think he had either dark brown or red hair) were the ones who freed said kingdom, and she thought everything was fine. Then, one day, she overheard her partner and friend having a talk, during which she hears them apparently saying that they love each other. She's shocked and leaves. Later on, she's betrayed by the two males and killed or sealed; not too sure.

Then she's reborn hundreds of years later. Both her ex-partner and friend are dead since long ago, and the protagonist is a baby/small child now who appears in some sort of church or palace and is received by someone from the royal family, if I'm not mistaken.

I might not be remembering everything correctly, but please, if someone knows the title or what might it be I'd be really really thankful. <333

Answer (score 0):

This is *[The Baby Dragon Tames the Crazy People](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-baby-dragon-tames-the-crazy-people)*.

> The Emperor of the Empire of Atlantis, Thalassa, in the depths of the sea. Contrary to her belief that days of abundance and happiness would continue,**she was betrayed by her lover and friend**, and sealed away for a **thousand years**. And when she opened her eyes again... Atlantis had already perished, and Thalassa was reborn as the **baby princess** and dragon heiress of the kingdom established by the traitors!

The first chapter covers the protagonist's first life, there she's an adult with long blue hair. She's the empress; I don't see any mention of her being a saint as well or anything similar. She has two faithful retainers, one of which is described as her lover, the other her friend.

[image]

After seeing the two men state that they love each other, they betray her and seal her away for a thousand years. She breaks the chains and reincarnates as a baby princess, being targeted by assassins and carried away by a maid.